# Used dropna(subset) but an error occurred

Tags: python, pandas, stringio

I'm practicing on data preprocessing using dropna method

I simply defined csv_data as

```
csv_data = \
'''A, B, C, D
1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0
5.0, 6.0,, 8.0
10.0, 11.0, 12.0,'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_data))
```

And I tried `df.dropna(subset=['C'])` for dropping rows where NaN appear in 'C' column

But I got an error below.

```
df.dropna(subset=['C'])
Traceback (most recent call last):

Input In [50] in <cell line: 1>
df.dropna(subset=['C'])

File C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:311 in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)

File C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:6002 in dropna
raise KeyError(np.array(subset)[check].tolist())

KeyError: ['C']
```

Anyone experienced this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your columns name contains whitespace which needs to be striped before performing `dropna`. So if you check your current column names you could see this,

```
>>> df.columns
Index(['A', ' B', ' C', ' D'], dtype='object')
                  ^^^
```

So one approach is to remove the spaces from column names.

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

Alternatively you can pass the exact column name(including spaces)

```
df.dropna(subset=[' C'])
                  ^^^^
```

Comment: Alternatively `df.dropna(subset=[" C"])` would work.